# align text in uiTextField XX pixels to the right (xcode)

Tags: iphone, textfield, alignment, pixel

I have a custom background for an `UITextField`. But the first 20 pixels of the `UITextField` are taken by the design. The text should start 30 pixels from the left. I have searched quite a bit, but I couldn't find it. I have seen things like overriding properties, but is that really necessary for something this basic?

Comment: is it possible for your `UITextField` to be more than 1 line long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen two different solutions:

- add an empty `UIView` as a `leftView` property of U`ITextView`
- subclass UITextField, and override methods `textRectForBounds:` `editingRectForBounds:` - just return frame with insets applied

IMHO the second one is more elegant.

Example:
.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BlackTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat paddingRight, paddingTop, paddingLeft, paddingBottom;
@end
```

.m:

```
#import "BlackTextField.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation BlackTextField
@synthesize paddingTop, paddingBottom, paddingLeft, paddingRight;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {        
        self.paddingRight   = 10;
        self.paddingLeft    = 10;
        self.paddingTop     = 5;
        self.paddingBottom  = 5;        
    }
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds 
{
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + self.paddingLeft, bounds.origin.y + self.paddingTop, bounds.size.width - self.paddingLeft - self.paddingRight, bounds.size.height - self.paddingTop - self.paddingBottom);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds 
{
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

@end
```

Comment: Im not the OP but can you share on how to achieve the second bullet? I am looking to do the same

Answer (score -1):

the simplest way to do is, create a `UIImageView` and put `UITextField` on it.

problem solved.

FYI: you could subclassing `UITextField`, but that would be huge and complex job to do. as i would not recommended as not standart view and could have many pitfall in current and future.

Comment: I commented on the answerer above about subclassing but the only problem with your way is what if you were you using a UIColor patternImage originally? I do not see how you can achieve that by doing your way.